# In laravel the otp is not send to emailid for resetpassword

Tags: one-time-password

The otp has successfully generate and it successfully saved in db table, but the otp is not send/received in emailid???......

I am experting that the otp was send/received to emailid........

```
public function login()
    {
        return view('auth.otp-login');
    }

    // Generate OTP
    public function generate(Request $request)
    {
        # Validate Data
        $request->validate([
            'reset_mailid' => 'required|exists:vs360_tables,mailid'
        ]);
        
        # Generate An OTP
        // Create a new instance of the Request class
        $request_mail_id = $request->input('reset_mailid');
        
        // Call the generateOtp() method with the correct argument type

        $verificationCode = $this->generateOtp($request_mail_id);

        $message = "Your OTP To Login is :- ".$verificationCode->otp;
        # Return With OTP 

         return redirect()->route('otp.verification', ['reset_mailid' => $verificationCode->reset_mailid])->with('success',  $message); 
    }

    public function generateOtp($reset_mailid)
    {
        $user = User::where('mailid', $reset_mailid)->first();

        # User Does not Have Any Existing OTP
        $verificationCode = VerificationCode::where('reset_mailid', $user->reset_mailid)->latest()->first();

        $now = Carbon::now();

        // dd($now);

        if($verificationCode && $now->isBefore($verificationCode->expire_at)){
            return $verificationCode;
        }

        // Create a New OTP
        return VerificationCode::create([
            'reset_mailid' => $reset_mailid,
            'otp' => rand(100000, 999999),
            'expire_at' => $now->addMinutes(10)
        ]);
    }
```

How to Solve this error?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that even vardump could help